# How to sort array properly?

Tags: angular, typescript

i have a model like this:

```
export class ProductAvarageRating {
  productId: number;
  avarageRating: any;
}
```

In Parent, i get that array from API that is not sorted. I initialize component in html like this:

```
<app-my-products-ratings
          [ratings]="ratings"
        ></app-my-products-ratings>
```

i Call an component:

```
export class MyProductsRatingsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() ratings: ProductAvarageRating[] = []; //data from parent

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ratings.sort((a, b) =>
      a.productId > b.productId ? 1 : b.productId > a.productId ? -1 : 0
    );
  }
}
```

My question is, why `ratings` is not sorted when i call `sort` function? What im doing wrong here? Maybe i need to call `sort` function somewhere else?

**EDIT**

i cuted not necesery information, but my child component have two `@Input()`,

```
export class MyProductsRatingsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() ratings: ProductAvarageRating[] = []; //data from parent
  @Input() watchedProducts: WatchedProduct[] = [];
  //same staf as above
```

And parent's html:

```
<app-my-products-ratings
          [watchedProducts]="watchedProducts"
          [ratings]="ratings"
        ></app-my-products-ratings>
```

**EDIT2**

Based on Patryk's answer, i get an error on `set ratings(...)...`:

> A 'set' accessor parameter cannot have an initializer.

**EDIT3**

My `Parent` have two `Childs` and i call it in `parent's` html:

```
<div>
    <app-my-products-watched
      [watchedProducts]="watchedProducts"
    ></app-my-products-watched>

    <app-my-products-ratings
      [watchedProducts]="watchedProducts"
      [ratings]="ratings"
    ></app-my-products-ratings>
</div>
```

Comment: Do all the elements in `ratings` have valid `productId`?

Comment: Yes, all have diffrent ID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using the set method @Input() (there is a chance that input is passed to the child, after ngOnInit)

```
_ratings: ProductAvarageRating[] = [];

@Input()
set ratings(ratings: ProductAvarageRating[]) {
   this._ratings = ratings;
   this._ratings=  this._ratings.sort((a, b) =>
      a.productId > b.productId ? 1 : b.productId > a.productId ? -1 : 0
   );
}
```

Thanks to that it will be invoked each time when input would change.

EDIT:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

export class ProductAvarageRating {
  productId: number;
  avarageRating: any;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
      <ng-container *ngFor="let rating of _ratings">
          <pre>{{rating | json}}</pre>
      </ng-container>
  `
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;

  _ratings: ProductAvarageRating[] = [];

  @Input()
  set ratings(ratings: ProductAvarageRating[]) {
    this._ratings = [...ratings];
    this._ratings=  this._ratings.sort((a, b) =>
        a.productId > b.productId ? 1 : b.productId > a.productId ? -1 : 0
    );
  }
}

//in parent
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<hello  [ratings]="ratings"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>`
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  ratings = [{productId: 2}, {productId: 1}];
}
```

Comment: In child html i iterate in `ratings`, so based on your answer i need to change `ratings` to `_ratings` in my html? Or it will be still `ratings`?

Comment: I copy-pasted your answer, i get en error, that `A 'set' accessor parameter cannot have an initializer`

Comment: so probably it should be _ratings: ProductAvarageRating[]; 
and yes you should change ratings to _ratings in html

Comment: look into my edit, maybe it will be helpful. Maybe i need to move `set` to parent?

Comment: I edited my answer. Now It is a fully working solution. ;)

Comment: `HelloComponent` is a child to `AppComponent`?

Comment: yeah, If it is not enough, here is a link to example in stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-93zxig?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: I marked your answer, but i have some problem. What to do, when AppComponent have 2 childs? When i copy-pasted your answer, everything dissapear. My ParentComponent passing data to two childs. Then i call that childs in parent's html as i posted i original post. These components are two lists, and after pasted your answer, nothing shows. If you need more data, i can edit my post again

Comment: Anyway, look into my edited post, i will be glad if you could look on it again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186106/discussion-between-patryk-blazinski-and-michasaucer).